# Print csv file in unix

Tags: unix, csv, awk

I am trying to print only those records from a csv `file1.csv` where in col `$1` is not blank. Records meeting this criteria to be copied in another csv `file2.csv`

```
awk -F "," '{$1 !=""; OFS=","} {print $1,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

But instead it is regenerating the entire file1.csv with only the columns to be print

Am i missing an if expression here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
awk -F "," '$1 !=""{OFS=","; print $1,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

only print lines with non-empty value in first field.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
     { if($1 != "") print }' file1.csv > file2.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You have put the curly braces at the wrong point in `{$1 !=""; OFS=","}` it should be more like `$1 !="" {print ... }` , so you can try this instead:

```
awk -F, '$1 {print $1,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20}' OFS=, file1.csv > file2.csv
```